# Batch: How to check if network shared printer exists?

Tags: batch-file, printer, network-shares

I'm enable to check if network folder exists

```
IF EXIST \\192.168.1.2\SharedFolder\ (echo It exist)
```

but I'm not enable check if network printer exists.

```
IF EXIST \\192.168.1.2\printername (echo It exist)
```

Comment: You can list the printers on a server with 
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ge /c\\machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [script from Robvanderwoude.com](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php) tests for the existence of a printer:

```
REM NOTE: RUNDLL32.exe and PRINTUI.exe always return Errorlevel=0
REM The trick: Try to get the printer settings into a file
REM If No file is created = The Printer does not exist
SET PrinterName=FIT FP-32L Raster
SET TESTfile=%TEMP%\PrtExist.txt

REM Delete %TESTfile% to avoid false positives
DEL %TESTfile% /F /Q

REM Try to get the printer settings into a file
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xg /n "%PrinterName%" /f "%TESTfile%" /q

IF EXIST "%TESTfile%" (
    ECHO %PrinterName% printer exists
) ELSE (
    ECHO %PrinterName% printer does NOT exists
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic while searching for a way to improve my deleteprinters.bat to get around these popup messages "Printer not found", whom are interrupting my script.

But in this case, the easiest way to handle that is just to add /q parameter after RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry.

Just in case.